# display .dae file and render jpg texture from dae file definition path

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, kml, kmz

I have a set of `kmz` files and I want to separate out the `dae` files inside to display them individually by `three.js`.

I found that these `dae` skin renderings are jpg files, and the paths to these files are defined in the `dae` file:

```
    <library_images>
        <image id="ImageNo2F">
            <init_from>.\texture\35748_0001009011_6283.jpg</init_from>
        </image>
        <image id="ImageNo1F">
            <init_from>.\texture\10608_2064.jpg</init_from>
        </image>
        <image id="ImageNoRoof">
            <init_from>.\texture\ROOF_1LG9R6P0RD.jpg</init_from>
        </image>
    </library_images>
```

dae example file: https://gitlab.com/po_developer/kml-file-exp/-/tree/main

I previewed the image through the [online service](https://products.aspose.app/3d/viewer?session=efa9530f-d6f9-4589-856a-407f8210c35b), and indeed the skin of the model is only black when no image is loaded.This service also doesn't seem to support loading textures.

[image]

I can only find [examples](https://git.ucsc.edu/jlao3/CMPM163Labs/-/blob/b82ac923de015467c3e882fb1142aae74c14eb55/three.js-master/examples/webgl_loader_kmz.html) of loading `kmz` files so far, and I don't know how to load `dae` textures for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

When textures are defined in the Collada asset, `ColladaLoader` automatically loads and applies them to the respective materials. So there is no need for a manual (additional) loading process. I suggest you use the basic Collada example [webgl_loader_collada](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada) as a code template.

BTW: I've tested your asset from GitLab on my Computer and realized its definitions are buggy. It refers to geometries via `instance_geometry` (the IDs are `GeometryNo2F8`and `GeometryNo1F8`) which are not defined in the asset. You need to fix this otherwise `ColladaLoader` will throw an error.

Comment: thanks for your response.How can I get the source code for this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada)?I also feel that there is a problem with the definition of this file, but I don't know how to detect it. Can you teach me how to detect it? Through some software?

Comment: What are `GeometryNo2F8` and `GeometryNo1F8`? What will it correspond to?

Comment: I get this [alert](https://upload.cc/i1/2022/08/05/6iRKTF.png) when I try to convert the file to `.glft` format using [cesium](https://cesium.com/ion/assets/). His warning is that there are repeated id names in the file, such as `GeometryNo1F0` appearing twice, is this also a problem?

Comment: Here is the source code of the mentioned example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html. GeometryNo2F8and GeometryNo1F8 are IDs inside the Collada file. You can open it with a text editor, it's XML. Instead of converting the Collada file to glTF with Cesium, you can also try to import it into Blender and then export to glTF.

Comment: I have opened the xml file and checked, but I don't know how to fix it.
Are `GeometryNo2F` and `GeometryNo1F8` corresponding to one file? Or a piece of xml code? What is missing from this file? These IDs can only appear once in a `.dae` file? like css id?

Comment: When I try to open the file with `ColladaLoader` it does get an error, but the error code doesn't show which part is wrong.